# Cloth does not follow hook

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have an animation of a cloth sim where the ends are being moved with hooks(and pins) and it works for like 80% of the animation until the cloth just stops obeying one of the hooks and that end stays still. (and no its not just in the viewport, it shows up in the final render also)

[image: moving through frames]

Cloth sims are always super buggy for me, would adding more ram to blender help solve?

Comment: hello, please share your file (share the link it will give you once uploaded): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: figured it out, it was the cache